# zshell grep negative lookbehind

Tags: regex, grep, zsh

I'm trying to play around w/ a negative lookbehind regex, but I can't seem to get it to work in my zshell.  Am I doing this wrong?

> echo "Nate or nate" | grep "(\?<!N)a"

This should match the `a` in **nate** but ***NOT*** the `a` in **Nate**...right?

Comment: zsh or bash it's the same thing. But good question and accepted answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When I think of lookahead or lookbehind assertions, I think of Perl. You will need to use perl-regexp and single quotes to find the `a` in `nate`:

```
echo "Nate or nate" | grep -P '(?<!N)a'
```

Comment: `bash: !grep: event not found`

Comment: @Cerin: You will need `GNU grep`. I'd say your flavor doesn't support Perl-regex.

Comment: I had the same problem today and your answer was the only one that  worked (in bash, actually ...). Does lookahead/lookbehind not work at all (without PCRE) or do I just have to escape particular characters to make it work?

Comment: @Griddo: Unfortunately no amount of escaping will help. You're version of `grep` must support the PCRE to use look-around expressions. HTH.

Comment: @Cerin The `event not found` message is from your shell. If `!` is not escaped or quoted, `bash` will search through your history for a matching command.

Comment: use grep -P which is PCRE

Answer (score 1):

It should.  However, `grep` will print out any line with a match.

If you'd like `grep` to print out only the parts of the line it matches, you should give it the `-o` option.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different regex flavours, but the regex for grep should probably look like this: `"(?<!N)a"`.

Answer (score 0):

First off you want to use single quotes (double quotes in zsh will try to expand the `!N`), you probably want extended regexen (`grep -E`). Also depending on your version of grep, it may not support 0-width assertions at all, check your `man 7 re_format`.